# Rake task in Jenkins not accessing config yaml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, rabbitmq, database-migration, rake-task

Came across an issue when deploying a code change to our development environment via Jenkins. The Jenkins build gets stuck while running `rake db:migrate` on the following code in the initializer folder.

```
 AMQP_URL_PATH =  "#{AMQP_CONFIG[:protocol]}://#{AMQP_CONFIG[:user]}:#{Rails.application.secrets[:amqp_api_password]}@#{AMQP_CONFIG[:host]}/#{AMQP_CONFIG[:virtual_host]}"
```

As you can see it is trying to access two yaml files `amqp.yml` and `secrets.yml`. I can confirm both files exist on the dev box within the config folder.

**local** the code produces the following good url

```
amqps://user:password@10.118.1.134/virtualhost
```

**development** the code only returns `://:@`

The Jenkin's build error is this.

```
15:59:21 URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): ://:@
```

As you can see none of the interpolated values are making it to the url string when this is running in Jenkins. This is the only change that has occurred in this push and if I hard code the path the build works perfectly. How do I get Jenkins to access these YAML files when running rake tasks during the build deployment?

**Development:**
Rails 4.2.5
Ruby 2.2.2
**Local:** 
Rails 4.2.5
Ruby 2.2.3